# What is the convention for storing files containing action filter classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some action filters that I want to apply to more than one controller. I looked around but can see no MVC conventions on where to place these files. The only place I was able to see them used was in NerdDinner and in that case all I could find was an onactionexecuting method that was inside of a controller.

For those of you who use Action Filters. Where do you place these in the MVC file structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go into a folder in the same level as the `Models` `Views` and `Controller` level, called `ActionFilters`.

I've also seen them go into a subfolder under `Controllers`, since they normally apply to actions on controllers.

Comment: Putting them under `Controllers` is a pretty good idea.  I like that.

Answer (score 0):

I place all `ActionFilter` classes in a folder simply called `Filters` in the MVC project.

However, my team recently created a `Web.Mvc.Common` project, and that's where we put the `Filters` folder now, so that they can easily be reused by other projects.